# How to parse string to date in xslt 2.0

Tags: string, date, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible to convert strings like `30042013` (30 April 2013) to a date format?

So I can use it later in functions like `format-date`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`fn:dateTime($arg1 as xs:date?, $arg2 as xs:time?)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-dateTime) will convert its arguments to `xs:dateTime`.

Just use [`fn:substring()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring) and [`fn:concat()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat) to cut out the relevant parts and join them as `yyyy-mm-dd` before passing that to `fn:dateTime`.

Answer (score 13):

Like Tomalak said, you can use `substring()` and `concat()` to build a string you can cast as an `xs:date()` (It doesn't sound like you want a dateTime.)

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="in" select="'30042013'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="xs:date(concat(
            substring($in,5,4),'-',
            substring($in,3,2),'-',
            substring($in,1,2)))"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-date($date,'[MNn] [D], [Y]')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces (with any XML input)

```
April 30, 2013
```