# How to convert String to Date YYYY-MM-DD using XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt-2.0

I need to convert 11/14/2016 - This is String Data Type. I need to convert it to 2016-11-14 using XSLT 2.0. Please let me know how to proceed? I don't want to use subString method. I tried format-date() function from xslt 2.0 but not successful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse string to date in xslt 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851726/how-to-parse-string-to-date-in-xslt-2-0)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this. You can use the `tokenize` function instead, if you do not want to use substring.

Assuming an input XML like:

```
<string>11/14/2016</string>
```

When run against a style sheet below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="target_string">
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(string, '/')[last()]"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(string, '/')[1]"/>
            <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="tokenize(string, '/')[2]"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <date1>
            <xsl:value-of select="xs:date($target_string)"/>
        </date1>
        <date2>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-date(xs:date($target_string), '[MNn] [D], [Y]')"/>
        </date2>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

produces:

```
<date1>2016-11-14</date1><date2>November 14, 2016</date2>
```

Comment: I tried with above example and got this error below:
Could not transform xml with the given xslt.
Reason: Invalid date "--" (Year is less than four
digits)  - My input was - 11/14/2016

Comment: I do not know how you implement it, but the code itself is working. See it here (http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQaEY)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that XSLT is following ISO 8601 which should be yyyy-mm-dd, so subString will be your only choice.

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#isoformats

Comment: Thank you Thomas.One more question - I have multiple date tags in incoming XML. How would I achieve that with one date template? Do I have to create separate templates for each tag?

Comment: Not sure what is your exact requirement, but you can try functions, reference:
https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/09/03/trxml.html