# Need to change the date format into the string using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having the date with numeric format, I need to change into the string format

Input XML(Month/Day/Year):

```
<Field>03/01/2021</Field>
```

XSLT I have tried:

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="in" select="Field"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="date" select="xs:date(concat(
      substring($in,/),'-',
      substring($in,/),'-',
      substring($in,/)))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-date($date,'[MNn] [D], [Y]')"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected Output is:

```
March 1, 2021
```

Comment: You can refer to this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851726/how-to-parse-string-to-date-in-xslt-2-0 which seems to do exactly what you need.

Comment: `substring($in,/)` makes no sense.