# need to compare the date with slash type

Tags: xml, date, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to compare the date, I had try the date-format, but its not working

XML:

```
<renewalDate>2/15/2022</renewalDate>
```

XSL I'm using:

```
    <xsl:variable name="ShortDate" select="xs:date('2/15/2022')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="RenewalDate" select="xs:date(renewalDate)"/>
    <xsl:if test="$RenewalDate &gt;= $ShortDate">
    <xsl:text>Date Expired<xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
```

Its not working and even I tried with format-date, then also I'm getting error like can't compare xs:string with xs:number.

Comment: Your date-format  is not correct for xs:date. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851802/3710053 on how you can solve that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates must be in YYYY-MM-DD format. Try it this way:

```
<xsl:variable name="rc" select="tokenize(renewalDate,'/')" />
<xsl:variable name="renew" select="concat($rc[3], format-number(number($rc[1]), '-00'), format-number(number($rc[2]), '-00'))" />
<xsl:variable name="ShortDate" select="'2022-02-15'"/>
<xsl:if test="xs:date($renew) ge xs:date($ShortDate)">Date Expired</xsl:if>
```